# Memcached as a second level cache for openjpa

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa, memcached, second-level-cache

I use tomcat + openejb (tomee) + openjpa (for persistence).
I'd like to add a memcached as a second-level cache for persistence.
I know that this is possible for Hibernate via hibernate-memcached, but as we work with opejpa implementation I'd like to do this for JPA, not Hibernate.

I prefer integration by changing persistance.xml configuration and not Java solution.

Is there any way to configure such a thing?

I'd really appreciate any recommendation on this issue.

Thanks!